# Организация файлов проекта на с

Tags: c++, c

Есть проект, в нем подпака inc для хранения заголовков, проект также подтягивает файлы общие с другими проектами, в частности там cpp и h, пока они сосредоточены в папке coommon в проектной директории. Где правильно с т.з организации больших проектов должны располагаться такие "общие"(межпроектные) файлы??? В common тоже делать папку inc?

Comment: Да, каждая библиотека имеет папки `inc` и `src` для заголовков и реализаций соответственно.

Comment: Лучше делать оглавления ("подпапки") внутри корнегого inc. Это облегчит последующую миграцию подсистем в другие проекты.